# db fields not included in the form are cleared when creating a model form instance

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a model, and when it's saved, it generates a special account_code.  This is used on the backend and shouldn't be included in the form because it's not something that should be editable by the user.

I just noticed that when I create the form after submission:

```
AccountForm(request.POST, request=request, instance=account)
```

Since account_code isn't included in the POST data, it's overwritten by the post.

From what I saw here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-developers/w8UKCLjOMpg that's normal behavior.

Is there a way to make it, rather than assuming missing fields are empty, have it skip those fields maintaining their previous value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a field is included in the form's Meta class `exclude` value, or you have a `fields` value which doesn't include that field, it will not be modified on form save.